# how to disable control your video,music and more in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, webbrowser-control

[image]
[image]

i have 7 button gaming mouse when i press back button on mouse this media dialog appear , when i scroll anywhere on any tab this is also appear . please tell me how can i disable this one its very irritative .
i already disable `hardware media key hendling` and `Global Media Controls Modern UI` from  chrome://flags/

Answer (score 0):

This was finally resolved.

Near the scrolling wheel is a dpi button, which also can be used to switch
between normal and media mode by holding it for 3 seconds. In the media mode the wheel controls the volume and does not scroll.